# Grid serialization in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get product grid in my custom module using grid serialization in magento 2??

How to do Grid serialization in magento 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Product grid serialization

In your  Tabs.php

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
{
     .......

     $this->addTab(
            'productgrid',
            [
                'label' => __('Select Product'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('modulename/*/actionname', ['_current' => true]),
                'class' => 'ajax',

            ]
        );

       ............
}
```

In your controller xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root">
    <block class="Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Questions\Edit\Tab\Productgrid" name="company.module.edit.tab.productgrid"/>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="productgrid_grid_serializer">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">position</argument>
            <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">company.module.edit.tab.productgrid</argument>
            <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedUpsellProducts</argument>
            <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
            <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
</layout>
```

In your Controller php

```
class Productgrid extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{

protected $resultLayoutFactory;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
    $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
}



public function execute()
{
    $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest());
    $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
    $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('company.module.edit.tab.productgrid')
        ->setProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('products', null)); 
    return $resultLayout;
}
}
```

Your Productgrid.php

```
class Productgrid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

protected $_coreRegistry = null;


protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Company\Module\Model\yourFactory $yourFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    array $data = []
) {

    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_yourFactory = $yourFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}


protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('product_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);

}




protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in product flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_products') {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        } else {
            if ($productIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}



protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        '*'
    );
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'type' => 'radio',
                'html_name' => 'products_id',
                'required'  => true,
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
            ]
        );



    $this->addColumn(
        'name',
        [
            'header' => __('Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-name',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-name'
        ]
    );


    $this->addColumn(
        'sku',
        [
            'header' => __('SKU'),
            'index' => 'sku',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-sku'
        ]
    );



    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}


public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->_getData(
        'grid_url'
    ) ? $this->_getData(
        'grid_url'
    ) : $this->getUrl(
        'modulename/*/actionname',
        ['_current' => true]
    );
}


protected function _getSelectedProducts()
{

    $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedProducts());

    return $products;
}


public function getSelectedProducts()
{
    $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if(!isset($tm_id)) {
        $tm_id = 0;
    }

    // if you save product id in your custom table 

    $collection = $this->_yourFactory->create()->load($tm_id);
    $data =  $collection->getProductId();
    $products = explode(',',$data);

    $proIds = array();

    foreach($products as $product) { 
        $proIds[$product] = array('id'=>$product);
    }

    return $proIds;
}


  }
```

This is for radio button in grid

Comment: if I do checkbox I'm not getting the selected product in the POST? do you have any idea?

Comment: I didn't try with a checkbox, Possibility  in a hidden field  checkbox value is not added while you click on checkbox check that

did you try @Vladimir Kerkhoff answer? it is for checkbox

Comment: I am also facing the same problem : not getting selected product id

Comment: have yuo get any solution for checkbox?

Comment: I did not check with Checkbox

Answer (score 1):

The grid serialisation is available by using the `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer` block class in your layout file. For example I used it in a sales order view tab that is loaded thru ajax the following way:

Layout file of the controller path that is accessed when clicking on the tab:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Genmato\BackorderStatus\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Tab\BackorderItem" name="sales.order.view.tab.backorderitem"/>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="backorderitem_grid_serializer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">qty</argument>
                <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">sales.order.view.tab.backorderitem</argument>
                <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getCollection</argument>
                <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">backorder_status</argument>
                <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">items</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</layout>
```

The tab extends the `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended` class (and implements `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface`) to build the grid.

Within the `_prepareColumns()` method you need your id field as checkbox type:

```
$this->addColumn(
            'item_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'values' => $this->getCollection(),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'item_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
```

and the an editable field:

```
$this->addColumn(
        'qty_backordered',
        [
            'header' => __('Backorder Qty'),
            'name' => 'qty_backordered',
            'type' => 'number',
            'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
            'index' => 'qty_backordered',
            'editable' => true,
            'edit_only' => true,
            'header_css_class' => 'col-position',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-position',
        ]
    );
```

As the `sales_order_view` form doesn't have a form or save action I had to add it thru an extra button and use an `AJAX` post to store the values, if the form is already used with a form this should not be needed and values should be posted on save of the form.