# Magento2 - Custom Admin Module with Grid Serializer - how to post more than 1 input fields

Tags: magento2, grid, grid-serlization

I have successfully implemented serialized grid in my custom module. Steps are same as this - [Grid serialization in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95805/grid-serialization-in-magento-2/95830#95830)

However there is only 1 input field - `position`. I need 2 input fields - `position` and `qty`. But when i write 2 `input_names` only 1 field gets posted in POST data. I want data of both.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**File:**  /app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Customgrid/Edit/Tab/Gridfile.php

`_prepareColumns` function:

```
$this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'header'       => __('Qty'),
                'name'         => 'qty',
                'type'         => 'number',
                'validate_class'   => 'validate-number',
                'index'        => 'qty',
                'editable'     => true,
                'edit_only'    => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-qty',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-qty'
            ]
        );

    $this->addColumn(
            'position'
            [
                'header'       => __('Position'),
                'name'         => 'position',
                'type'         => 'number',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index'        => 'position',
                'editable'     => true,
                'edit_only'    => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-position',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-position'
            ]
        );
```

**File:** `/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/frontname_controller_action.xml`

**WAY 1**

```
     <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="position" xsi:type="string">position</item>
            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string">qty</item>
     </argument>
```

**WAY 2**

```
      <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">position,qty</item>
       </argument>
```

**WAY 3**

```
      <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">position</item>
       </argument>
```

None of these work. First way only posts qty. Second way gives a blank page. Third way only posts position and not qty.

Any ideas as to what the correct syntax is ?

I have checked core files but all of them only use one input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Magento allows more than 1 input field. It is only possible if serialized grid is set to **Multi-dimensional** mode.

**--SOLUTION--**

It can be achieved in following way:

**File**: `/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/folder_controller_action.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="custom_grid_serializer">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">qty</item>
            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">sort_order</item>
        </argument>
     </arguments>
</block>
```

**--TRACING--**

**File:** `/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/grid.js`

In `grid.js` If you notice `rowinit` function, it checks the length of  `inputs`. If total no. of `inputs` is greater then zero then it will execute a `for` loop:

```
if(this.multidimensionalMode){
    var inputs = $(row).select.apply($(row), selectors.flatten());
    if(checkbox && inputs.length > 0) { 
           //some core JS code
           for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                //some other core JS code     
           }
    }
}
```

Now, this `for` loop is only executed if `multidimensionalMode` is set to `true`. If you trace back, you will find that `multidimensionalMode` is set in `initialize` function in following code:

```
initialize: function(hiddenDataHolder, predefinedData, inputsToManage, grid, reloadParamName){
        //some core JS code

        this.inputsToManage       = inputsToManage;
        this.multidimensionalMode = inputsToManage.length > 0;

        //some other core JS code
}
```

So, `multidimensionalMode` uses `length` property on `inputsToManage` which is the `JSON` form of our `input_names` argument defined in our `layout xml` file.

So, you have to declare `xsi:type` of `input_names` as `array` in `layout xml` file and assign values to the `name` attribute of `item` starting from zero(as array indices are numbered). This will form a `JSON` as below:

```
var inputsToManage = [{0:'qty',1:"sort_order"}];
inputsToManage.length = 1
```

Hence, `this.multidimensionalMode` will now be set to `true`

Comment: @KeyurShah - glad it helped :)

Comment: can you please share the entire source code? i am working on same things but not able to get proper input value

Comment: It's not working for me as well, How the hidden input fields get created and I will get values of this field in controller action?

Comment: I have added my question on this link.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310012/mangeto-2-admin-grid-serialization-of-multiple-input-fields