# Magento 2 : How to serialise multiple values in Custom Module Product Grid

Tags: magento2, product-grid, grid-serlization

In My custom module Product Grid, I Need to serialize **A, B, and C** values by the user select. the additional fields are not actually reloaded, only an array containing the product_ids currently. How can I post the data with multiple column values?

Please find the attachment for the  better understaning.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento2 - Custom Admin Module with Grid Serializer - how to post more than 1 input fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96293/magento2-custom-admin-module-with-grid-serializer-how-to-post-more-than-1-in)